# Delphi: Having trouble creating a sign in and sign up function in my program

Tags: delphi

I'm stuck in a part of my coding for a program. I tried to make a sign in, sign up program on its own so if I got it right I could just copy and paste the coding into my original coding but I failed miserably.

I'm using a text file to store all the information. I want the users to be able to sign in using a password and username that I have stored in the text file. To sign up the user should enter their name, password, username and email adress, all into different edit boxes and click sign up.

I tried to code it so all the information would end up with a `*` separating it and the copy the information before the `*` into a seperate panel or memo for later use when the user wants to sign in.

I also in the process tried to declare the text file all over the program, but failed miserably at that as well. I really want to move on with my coding but this is literally stopping me.

Here's my code so far:

```
var
  myFile : Textfile;
  sLyn,
  sNaam,
  sEmail,
  sPassword,
  sUsername,
  sEditP,
  sEditE,
  sEditU,
  sEditN : string;
  iPos : integer;
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.Clear;
  RichEdit1.Paragraph.TabCount := 3;
  RichEdit1.Paragraph.Tab[0] := 90;
  RichEdit1.Paragraph.Tab[1] := 180;
  RichEdit1.Paragraph.Tab[2] := 270;

  //1
  Assignfile(myFile,'Data.txt');
  //2
  If FileExists('Data.txt') <> True Then begin
    exit;
  //Stop coding as dit nie bestaan nie
  end;
  //3
  Reset(myFile); ReadLN(myFile,sLyn);
  //Naam en van, Password, Email Adres, Username

  iPos := POS('',sLyn);
  sNaam := COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
  Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
  iPos := POS('',sLyn);
  sPassword := COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
  Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
  iPos := POS('*',sLyn);
  sEmail:= COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
  Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
  sUsername := sLyn; //Toets of die persoon als ingevul het

  If Length(EditCreatePassword.Text) = 8 then begin
    sEditP := EditCreatePassword.Text;
    sEditP := sPassword;
  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter a password of 8 characters');
    exit;
  end;

  If Length(EditEmail.Text) > 0 then begin
    sEditE := EditEmail.Text;
    sEmail := sEditE;
  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter your email adress');
    exit;
  end;

  If Length(EditName.text) > 0 then begin
    sEditN := EditName.Text;
    sNaam := sEditN;
  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter your name and surname');
    exit;
  end;

  If Length(EditUser.Text) <9 then begin
    sEditU := EditUser.Text;
    sUsername := sEditU;
  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter a username of 8 characters');
    exit;
  end;

  Richedit1.Lines.Add(sNaam+''+sPassword+''+sEmail+''+sUsername+'');

  //4
  While Not EOF(myFile) Do
  //5
  begin
    ReadLN(myFile,sLyn); //Naam en van, Password, Email Adres, Username
    iPos := POS('*',sLyn);
    sNaam := COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
    Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
    iPos := POS('',sLyn);
    sPassword := COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
    Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
    iPos := POS('',sLyn);
    sEmail:= COPY(sLyn,1,iPos-1);
    Delete(sLyn,1,iPos+1);
    sUsername := sLyn;
    If Length(EditCreatePassword.Text) = 8 then begin
      sEditP := EditCreatePassword.text;
      sPassword := sEditP;
    end
    else begin
      ShowMessage('Please enter a password of 8 characters');
      exit;
    end;

    If Length(EditEmail.Text) > 0 then begin
      sEditE := EditEmail.Text;
      sEmail := sEditE;
    end
    else begin
      ShowMessage('Please enter your email adress');
      exit;
    end;

    If Length(EditName.text) > 0 then begin
      sEditN := EditName.Text;
      sNaam := sEditN;
    end
    else begin
      ShowMessage('Please enter your name and surname');
      exit;
    end;

    If Length(EditUser.Text) < 9 then begin
      sEditU := EditUser.Text;
      sUsername := sEditU;
    end
    else begin
      ShowMessage('Please enter a username of 8 characters');
      exit;
    end;

    Richedit1.Lines.Add(sNaam+''+sPassword+''+sEmail+''+sUsername+'');

  end;
  //6
  Closefile(myFile);
```

Any help on solving this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following will solve the exact problem you're having, but even
if not, it should help you greatly simplify your code for parsing lines read from
your data file. Simplification is nearly always a good thing to do with code.

Suppose you have a variable Line which contains the text of a line you've just read from your
file and contains something like

```
1a*2bc*3def*ghij
```

Then, you can use the built-in functionality of a TStringList to parse this to
extract the strings between the *s.  Here's a stand-alone routine which does that:

```
procedure TDefaultForm.TestParse;
var
  Line,
  S1,
  S2,
  S3,
  S4 : String;
  TL : TStringList;
begin
  Line := '1a*2bc*3def*4ghij';

  TL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    TL.Delimiter := '*';
    TL.DelimitedText := Line;
    S1 := TL[0]; // the 0 is because the lines of the stringlist contents are indexed from 0, not 1
    S2 := TL[1];
    S3 := TL[2];
    S4 := TL[3];
  finally
    TL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Put a breakpoint on TL.Free and use Ctrl-F7 to evaluate S1, etc, you'll see that they contain '1a', '2bc', '3def', '4ghij'.

In your case, you would create the stringlist before you start reading from the file and
free it afterwards, of course.

The above code has no error checking, so would fail with a "list index out of bounds" error
on a line which had fewer than 3 *s.  In real code, at the minimum, you should check that
the index value you're using (as in TL[Index]) is less or equal to TL.Count - 1.

Of course, if this doesn't deal with the point you're stuck on, you'd better edit your q (not add a comment) to explain exactly what it is you *are* stuck on.